# Error with command substitution, bash and pipes

Tags: linux, bash, command, substitution

Using CentOS 6.4

Executing:

```
var1=$(softnas-cmd checkupdate | jq .success)
```

give me an error:

```
"parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9"
```

if I execute `var1=$(softnas-cmd checkupdate)` followed by `echo $var1` I get:

```
{"success" : true, "session_id" : 1935, "result" : {"success":true,"msg":"You are running the latest version","records":{"version":"2.1.3.el6.x86_64","newversion":"2.1.3.el6.x86_64","updateavailable":false,"msg":"You are running the latest version"},"total":4}}
```

if I then execute `var2=$(echo $var1 | jq .success)` this works and I get the expected:
true

ultimately I want to do this:

```
if [ $(softnas-cmd checkupdate | jq .succcess) = "true" ]; then
   echo "update required"
   ...
fi;
```

can anyone tell me how to format the command substitution so I can execute in one shot?

Thanks

Comment: What does `var1=$(softnas-cmd checkupdate)` followed by `echo "$var1"` (note the double-quotes!) print?

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-145 ~]$ var1=$(softnas-cmd checkupdate)
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-145 ~]$ echo "var1$"
var1$
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-145 ~]$
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-145 ~]$ echo $var1
{"success" : true, "session_id" : 32270, "result" : {"success":true,"msg":"You are running the latest version","records":{"version":"2.1.3.el6.x86_64","newversion":"2.1.3.el6.x86_64","updateavailable":false,"msg":"You are running the latest version"},"total":4}}
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-10-145 ~]$

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to parse the true/false after the string "updatevailable"? If so, try this:

```
res=`softnas-cmd checkupdate | sed -n "s/.*updateavailable\":\([tf][a-z]*\),.*/\1/p"`; 
if [ "$res" == "true" ]; then 
    echo "update required" ... 
fi;
```

if you are, however, trying to parse the true/false after the first "success" string, then:

```
res=`softnas-cmd checkupdate | sed -n "s/.*\"success\" : \([tf][a-z]*\), .*/\1/p"`; 
if [ "$res" == "true" ]; then 
    echo "update required" ... 
fi;
```

and parsing the second "success" string would be:

```
res=`softnas-cmd checkupdate | sed -n "s/.*\"success\":\([tf][a-z]*\), .*/\1/p"`; 
if [ "$res" == "true" ]; then 
    echo "update required" ... 
fi;
```

Comment: I am trying to do your first suggestion, parse out the 'updateavaialble' value. When I try your suggestion, $res is left with a null value. However if I assign res=`softnas-cmd checkupdate` and then res=`echo $res | sed ...`, $res contains the expected value, so it seems your suggestion is experiencing the same issue i encountered using the jq library

Comment: If the string is the one you posted, it should worked. I copied over to a file and test it from there by doing a cat. It might be the case that your script is providing output to stderr instead of stdout? if so, try softnas-cmd checkupdate 2>&1 | sed ....